# Can't have a global cache

Tags: python, caching, dogpile.cache

I have defined this cache file with `dogpile` [1]. But my problem is that when I invoke the key in different classes, it can't find the value. Eg, If I am running `cache.Cache.save("mykey", 123)` in the `main.py`, and during the execution I am retrieving the value in another module `submodule.py` with `cache.Cache.get("mykey")`, I can't retrieve the value. I get `NoValue`. It seems that I am not creating a unique and global cache for all my program.

All the `set` and `get` to the cache are made by this module `mycache.py`. Why this is happening?

[1] mycache.py

```
from dogpile.cache import make_region

region = make_region().configure('dogpile.cache.memory')
class Cache:

  @staticmethod
  def save(key, value):
    region.set(key, value)

  @staticmethod
  def get(key):
    return region.get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have solved this problem by saving the cache into a file.

```
region = make_region().configure('dogpile.cache.dbm',
                             expiration_time = 3600,
                             arguments = {
                                 "filename":"./cache_execution.dbm"
                             })
```